# How to define a data-area data-structure that is dim()?

Tags: rpgle

I would like to add the `DIM()` keyword to this - but the compiler complains?

```
$ConfEmlDS     UDS                  qualified DTAARA(TSACONFEML)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to code the DIM keyword for any variable that is mapped to a data area.

Here's how you can code your data structure:

First, define a template for your data structure elements:

```
 D $ConfEml_t      DS                  qualified template          
 D  $ConfEml                     41A                               
 D   $AllowYN                     1A   Overlay($ConfEml:1)         
 D   $EmailId                    40A   Overlay($ConfEml:2)
```

Then define your UDS as a qualified data structure with a subfield defined LIKEDS your template, with the DIM keyword.

```
 D $ConfEmlDs     UDS                  qualified dtaara(TSACONFEML)
 D  arr                                likeds($ConfEml_t) DIM(10)
```

To work with the data structure, code like this:

```
$ConfEmlDs.arr(1).$ConfEml
```